# Google sign in, can't get authentication in release, only when in debug

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, google-authentication

Why cant I get authentication in release mode but in debug mode? Have been trying to change the requestIdToken String with a hardcoded one, because if I try to change the RequestIdToken 'default_web_client_id' it just says "Change-Me" but can't be changed.

```
<string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">CHANGE-ME</string>
```

**Sign in options**

```
// Configure Google Sign In
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Comment: That string is read from your google-services.json file. You could have issues because your release and debug applications have different signatures. Add both certificates under project settings.

Comment: Sorry, where do you mean?

Comment: On the firebase console you can add applications under project settings. It's hidden in a gear above analytics. Add entries for both your debug and release certificates.

Comment: Do you mean another SHA Key? How do i get the release version of it then? uses a mac.

Comment: There should be a link there how to get your SHA fingerprint. You can also check out the authentication docs.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks